# Costly function inside nested Modules

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming, broken-code

The function `initDataTable` simply reset all data to `Black` first, then set the bottom right quarter to `Blue`.

```
dataTable = Table[1, 10, 10];

someCostlyFunction[] := Module[
   {a},
   
   For[i = 1, i < 1000, i++, a += i];
   a
   ];

changeColor[coord_] := Module[
   {},
   
   someCostlyFunction[]; (*If comment this line, the result is correct*)
   RGBColor[0, 0, 1]
   ];

initDataTable[] := Module[
   {},
   
   (*first reset all data to zero*)
   For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
    For[j = 1, j <= 10, j++,
      dataTable[[i]][[j]] = RGBColor[0, 0, 0];
     ]
    ];
   
   (*change some data based on some logics*)
   For[i = 6, i <= 10, i++,
    For[j = 6, j <= 10, j++,
       dataTable[[i]][[j]] = changeColor[{i, j}];
      ];
    ];
   ];

initDataTable[]
ArrayPlot@dataTable
```

The output are all black, the function call `changeColor` looks failed. If I comment out the code `someCostlyFunction` within `changeColor`, the data table initialization is correct.

My Mathematica project become bigger and bigger, so I need to use nested Module calls, hope someone could help me solve this problem.

Comment: I believe that part of your problem is `someCostlyFunction[]:=Module[{a},For[i=1,i<1000,i++,a+=i];a];` where you are incrementing the uninitialized value `a` a thousand times. If you change that to `someCostlyFunction[]:=Module[{a=0},For[i=1,i<1000,i++,a+=i];a];` and do not comment out your costly function then some of your problems appear to go away. I believe there is still at least one more problem in your code, but this might be a good first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "side effect". In order to correct, it is sufficient to localize `i`

```
someCostlyFunction[] := 
  Module[{a = 0, i}, For[i = 1, i < 1000, i++, a += i];
   a];
```

Generally, the procedural style of the `C`-language that you are using is provoking such side effects. Try that your functions do not have them at all

```
dataTable=initDataTable[]
```

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks a lot.